# can't run sqlplus from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, build, sqlplus

I'm trying to run an ant target using an apply tag with the executable property set to sqlplus but I'm getting this error:

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sqlplus" (in
>   directory "D:\builds\xxxx"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

My build xml file look like this:

```
<target name="xxxx">
    <apply dir="${root.dir}/test" executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true" output="${logs.dir}/xxxx.log">
        <arg line="${db.user}/${db.pass}@${db.direct}" />
        <srcfile prefix="@"/>
        <fileset dir="${root.dir}/tests" casesensitive="false">
            <include name="xxxx.sql"/>
        </fileset>
    </apply>  
</target>
```

I m using Jenkins with Invoke Ant and I have sqlplus installed on my build machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Working Now. I created an environment variable **sqlplus** containing the url to sqlplus.exe. Then I used it in my ant file.

```
<apply dir="${root.dir}/test" executable="${env.sqlplus}" ...>
```

Comment: Got the same error when I installed Oracle XE while IntelliJ was already opened and somehow IntelliJ didn't notice additional row (sqlplus) in system paths. Restarting IntelliJ fixed the issue.